# How do I keep code DRY with multiple conditions across fat models?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-model

Though I am working with CakePHP, I think this problem would apply to any MVC framework.

Consider the following:

- Model A

  ```
  getAWithConditionOne()
  ```
- Model B

  ```
  getBWithConditionsTwo()
  ```
- Model C (Join Model between A & B)

  ```
  getCWithConditionOne()
  getCWithConditionTwo()
  getCWithConditionOneAndTwo()
  ```

Is there any established way to handle this situation without having to create three separate methods in the join model? It feels a lot like the Decorator pattern should be applied here but I do not see how to go about it.

Maybe I am just looking at the problem wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, there are different approaches.
from what I experienced and saw so far you can work with behaviors here.

the name of an existing behavior in that direction is "NamedScope" (found in github) and the others I cant find right now.

but basically you can set up named conditions in your model

```
public $scopes = array(
    'public' => array('Model.active'=>1),
    ...
)
```

which you could then combine in your queries and find() calls:

```
array('scope'=>array('Model.public', 'OtherModel.approved', ...)
```

etc.
the behavior joins them into a single conditions array.

Answer (score 0):

To me it sounds like a use case for the Strategy pattern. You would have a `getC` method, expecting a strategy as parameter. And each strategy would be a class with a `getConditions` method returning the conditions for the particular strategy.